# Migrate part of a Drupal 6 installation to a new Drupal 7 installation

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to migrate the users and the Forum nodes (including comments) from Drupal 6 Installation (current productive system) to a new Drupal 7 installation (staging system). I wanted to start from scratch with Drupal 7 so I did not go the upgrade way, but now I'm facing the problem that some data has to be migrated anyway.

I tried several Import/Export modules, but none really does what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.  It takes some coding but  but the documentation and example modules for it are very detailed and helpful. Basically you would create a migration class for the users (see [BeerUserMigration](http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/migrate_example/beer.inc)) and a class for the forum nodes (see [BeerNodeMigration](http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/migrate_example/beer.inc)).

One of the great things about this module is it creates a mapping between both data stores which allows you to rollback and re-run the migration until you get it right.